# Simple HTML "ALT" Tag Question. Please Help!

Tags: html

This may be a stupid question but I need help with the "ALT" HTML TAG.

Example:

I have an image on my website. I should be using the "ALT=IMAGE" tag in the HTML. I should also be using the "TITLE=IMAGE" tag. That way if someone can't see the image, it will have text and it's also great for SEO so crawlers can find my site. I've never used the alt tag because when I do, it adds a "popup" of the text when someone puts there mouse on the image. That being said, I want to use the ALT text for SEO but don't want the "popup" to come up since I'm using multiple images on my website and it would just be weird. How can I stop it from popping up?

This website "http://ekonline.com/" has ALT TAGS on all if not most of the images but when I mouse-over them, no text pops up... Why...

Please help. Thanks very much.

Comment: These are **atributes**, not tags.  And they aren't all-caps.

Comment: They are alt _attributes_, not _tags_. Showing tooltips for the alt and title attributes is common browser behaviour that you really shouldn't try to prevent. Can you explain why you think the tooltips are "weird"?

Comment: I posted this in a bit of a hurry. I figured their would be someone that would pick my post apart. I don't think tool-tips are weird. My site is made up of many complex tables and images and every image would popup a tool-tip when you scroll over it. Its unnecessary. I want the alt HTML in there for SEO reasons. 

PS - I know their not all caps. I was just trying to make my posting easier to read...

Comment: To make it easier to read, wrap them in ` characters: `alt` attribute

Answer (score 1):

Usually,

- The content of the `alt=` attribute is displayed if the image cannot be displayed (or image display is turned off).
- The content of the `title=` attribute is shown as a mouse popup when the mouse is moved over the image.

Use one or the other, or both, as appropriate.

Comment: ...except that HTML4 [syntactically requires the `alt` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/objects.html#edef-IMG) to be included for `<img>` elements, so under certain circumstances  you may not legally omit it.

Comment: @Phrogz I think he meant "fill" one or another, or both.

Comment: Exactly my problem. I'm using HTML4 so it requires it. At least according to W3C. I don't have to use it but I want to since I wont be using and flash and ALT is used by crawlers to help my SEO.

Answer (score 1):

Dude, your website is wrapped up in tables with lots of HTML garbage and you are using FLash for content, and you are worried about ALT tag because of SEO.. relax, just remove TITLE tag and you're fine. NHF.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_alt.asp

Comment: Fully aware of that. Information about alt attribute is relevant on w3schools.com, particularly this `Tip: To create a tooltip for an image, use the title attribute!`

Comment: ekonline.com isnt my website. I was using that as an example. I checked the code for that site and there is no tooltip bubble and hes using the alt tag...

Comment: @user690441 Ok then, you shouldn't have posted other people websites, it is not nice :) Have your solved you problem?

Comment: Not yet. I'm not sure if everyone understands my situation. Seems like a lot of unnecessary nonsense. My site is made up of many complex tables and images and every image would popup a tool-tip when you scroll over it. Its unnecessary. I want the alt HTML in there for SEO reasons. Anymore ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your talking about the tooltip's that are popping up. Title tags appear with the title once you hover over them with the mouse.

Comment: OK so what Im getting out of this is if I dont use the title tag, I dont get a tooltip. I can just use the alt tag. I tried just using the alt tag and I still get the tooltip pop up... I cant seem to get it to go away.

Comment: By the way, Im using Firefox 4 for my browser. I haven't tried any others yet. I don't want the tooltip to come up no matter what browser I use.

Answer (score 0):

The `alt` attribute is rendered as a tooltip in as of IE 7, this is a browser behavior and there is no easy way to change it, but since IE8 and any other browser you can use it without getting that bubble popping up.

Read more on this here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt_attribute

If you did want the tooltip that is generated by the title attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I figured it out. If I put name=text and alt=text in the HTML for the specific image, I get no tool-tip popup. Why... I have no idea... lol. Either way it works. Any ideas? I'm assuming because I have both name and alt in there instead of just alt... Thanks for your help!